# Transit visa for Muscat when flying to Canada

Tags: transit-visas, klm, muscat, oman-air

My parents who are Indian citizens in their sixties will be flying from India to Canada(visitor visa) with layover in Muscat and Amsterdam. There is a layover of 2.5 hrs in Muscat where they will be changing flights from Oman Air to KLM. Would they require a transit visa for that short duration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the IATA Travel Centre, if they transit within the international area within 24h on the same ticket then they can transit without a visa.
[image: Omavisa]

Comment: Is it possible to remain in the international transit area of the Muscat airport when transferring from Oman Air to KLM?  I'd assume, at a minimum, that they'd need to ensure that their bags were checked through to their final destination.

Comment: Thanks you, Mike!